# Querying nested subtrees in Cosmos DB

Tags: c#, azure-cosmosdb, document-database

Let's say I have a parent-child-grandchild-etc relationship in a Cosmos document, represented by the following JSON:

```
"id": "someUniqueString",
"peepsNkids": [
    "Jane": [
        "Joe": [],
        "Jocelyn": [
            "Jerry": [],
            "Jan": [
                "Tom": [],
                "Dick": [],
                "Harry": []
            ],
            "Jim": []
        ],
    "Mary": [
        "Moe": [],
        "Larry": [],
        "Dorothy": [
            "Eadie": [],
            "Phil": [],
            "Lucille": [
                "Desi Jr": []
            ]
        ]
    ]
]
```

How can I query cleanly (in Storage Explorer and C#) for a subtree that, using the syntax of the "Sub-documents" section of [this post titled "Query DocumentDB"](https://www.documentdb.com/sql/tutorial), would resolve to:

`SELECT * FROM peepsNkids.Jane.Jocelyn.Jan`

... with the expectation that the following would be returned?

```
[
    "Tom": [],
    "Dick": [],
    "Harry": []
]
```

I don't think I need to worry about the original id here. Worst case is that I get back multiple records that have `Jane.Jocelyn.Jan`, and since in my "real" setup the "names" are all unique ids, getting back multiple rows would indicate a serious schematic issue.

I can obviously create a potentially cyclical object model with `string name` and `List<PersonAndKids> peepsNkids`, then get back the *full* entry for the id `"someUniqueString"` and *then* traverse the objects with lots of `peepsNkids.TryGetValue("Jane", out firstParent)` kinds of stuff, but I'm looking for a way to do that in Cosmos rather than in my service's memory.

Comment: If you figured out the problem, please post it as a proper answer, and not as an edit to your question. That way, this question and answer can be properly voted on, accordingly.

Comment: @DavidMakogon That's the plan. For some reason, I thought I had to wait two days to answer my own question; thanks for the update.

Comment: @DavidMakogon Worth pointing out that I still am unable to use a query in the format shown [at the link I provided](https://www.documentdb.com/sql/tutorial), which remains an unanswered part of this question.

Answer (score 0):

#### Nested query does not work

Your mistake appears to be believing that you have to query a sort of "nested table" like you mention in your question with this...

```
SELECT * FROM c.peepsNkids.Jane.Jocelyn.Jan
```

Now you're right, that's *exactly* what's demonstrated as a nested query in [the link you provided](https://www.documentdb.com/sql/tutorial), which includes this query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Families.address.state
```

I don't see a way to execute that in Storage Explorer. It would be interesting to find out how to use this construction or if it's possible.

#### Composite field equivalent

It is, however, possible to do an equivalent query that selects a sort of "composite field" that equates to a table. Try this:

```
SELECT peepsNkids.Jane.Jocelyn.Jan FROM c
```

Or, better yet, to constrain that query to a specific document by id, try this:

```
SELECT peepsNkids.Jane.Jocelyn.Jan FROM c WHERE c.id = 'someUniqueString'
```

Comment: It's challenging to query in either Azure Storage Explorer or Data Explorer in the Azure portal, as both force queries to start with "SELECT * FROM c".